# Using where on a column resulting from UDF

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In my select i have a column which is resulting from UDF. Also the same column should be part of where clause. Other than calling UDF two times are there any other options. I have around 15K rows returning based on user search, because of this i would like to call UDF as it is slowing performance any advice on how to achieve this. Would like something similar to this.

```
SELECT EMP
    , SAL
    , Location
    , dbo.GetCompValue
      (EMP, SAL) AS CompValue
FROM   tblEmpSal
WHERE  CompValue > 5000;
```

Comment: What is the code for `dbo.GetCompValue`? You'll be best off ditching the UDF entirely most likely.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CROSS/OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT EMP, SAL,Location, s.CompValue
From tblEmpSal 
OUTER APPLY (SELECT dbo.GetCompValue(EMP,SAL) AS CompValue) s
WHERE s.CompValue > 5000
```

Answer (score 1):

UDFs are always a pig when it comes to Performance , you can change this function logic to make it an `In-Line table valued function`, Performance will be much better and in some cases it will also make use of the cached execution plans.

```
SELELCT EMP, SAL,Location, CompValue
FROM (
      SELECT EMP, SAL,Location, dbo.GetCompValue(EMP,SAL) AS CompValue
      From tblEmpSal
    )A 
WHERE A.CompValue > 5000
```

Comment: @JamieD77 opss missed that part of the question :) anyway have modified the query to make it call it only once.

Answer (score 0):

If the UDF's parameters are from a single table, one option (depending on how that table is used and the nature of the UDF) would be to add a persisted computed column to that table and then use that column in your SQL statements instead of repeatedly calling the UDF. This column could also potentially be indexed, although whether that has any benefit will depend on what else your query is doing.